# UIKit draw text with script font that is larger than the frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I'm not very good at explaining, so here's an image example of what happens when I use this font in a `UILabel`:

[image]

As you can see, the top and left side of the text are cut off. I've tried setting the `clipsToBounds` property of the label to `NO`, but I get the same result.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: This one helped me, I had the same issue: [klick][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment/8314197#8314197