# UIButton Custom font issue

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton, uifont, custom-font

I have added a custom font in to my application and i set that custom font for some of the buttons by sub classing the custom font,in xib custom font set perfectly

[image]

but while execute in device the font auto adjust to upside in all the button.

[image]

Here is my custom font sub class code.

```
@interface ButtonWithBebasNeueFont : UIButton 
@end
@implementation ButtonWithBebasNeueFont

- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:self.titleLabel.font.pointSize];
```

}

```
@end
```

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is a result of the font's ascender property being too small. You have two options:

1. Edit the font source directly (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314197/1064869))
2. Set the title edge insets of the button like so:

   ```
   self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT);
   ```

Just substitute `TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT` with your values.