# Why custom font moves text (change vertical alingment)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uilabel

I have this code, creating simple UILabel with some text and default font

```
        self.reviewCountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
        self.reviewCountLabel.text = @"1231 REVIEWS";
        self.reviewCountLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        self.reviewCountLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
//        self.reviewCountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kSTGFontAvantGardeBold size:18];
        [self addSubview:self.reviewCountLabel];
```

On the screen I get this:

[image]

BUT if I **uncomment** code which add custom font I will get this:

[image]

Can someone explain why I have vertical alignment to top here? (or help to solve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not aligning to top, but the geometry (ascenders, baselines, etc.) of the new font is simply different from the system font.  Not all fonts are as clean as others in this regard.

You can tweak the geometry using [Apple's Font Tool Suite](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), specifically the `ftxdumperfuser` command.  [Here is an older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment/8314197#8314197) with a very detailed description of how to use that tool to fix your issue.