# For eBook Kannada font (Nudi 01 e b.ttf) is converting to gibberish English font in iPad, iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts, epub

I've created a Kannada eBook using **Sigil**, Kannada fonts are working properly in Samsung, HTC, Sony (tested in some models). But not working in iPad, and iPhone.

Can anybody please suggest me some solutions for this?

[image]

Comment: maybe... will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8314197/1702413

Answer (score 1):

I believe the font you mention is a so-called "ASCII" font, rather than a Unicode-encoded font. In that case, correct display is a matter of luck and is not guaranteed. Even if it works on today's Sony devices, it might stop working tomorrow. According to the spec, EPUBs must be Unicode.

Yes, I am well aware of the issues involved in re-coding legacy content in ASCII encodings for Kannada and other Indic languages into Unicode. However, from the standpoint of future-proofing your content and guaranteeing operability across platforms, it is an investment that will prove worthwhile.

It would also be helpful if you could create a one-page, one-line book with this problem and post the XHTML and the content.opf file.

**UPDATE**

It appears that version 5.0 of Nudi includes Unicode-conformant fonts, see [this article](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/nudi-50-version-to-be-launched-on-tuesday/article4348603.ece), and also includes a converter.

Answer (score 1):

This mainly happens because of the missing font. Try to download Sigil font onto your device which cannot read kannada fonts.

Alternatively, if you have typed in MS Word using the Sigil Font then While saving select save options and tick the box "Embed Fonts". By doing this your document can be read in any device without the reader having that particular font.