# Centering a custom UIButton title with custom font

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, center, custom-font

I'm using some custom fonts I added to my project for the titles of `UIButton`. I am not able to set my custom fonts in IB, and I've read in some posts that it is not possible yet in the last XCode version, is that right? So, currently, I'm setting the font for the titles programmatically. The point is that, as in IB the font is set to the default, when I set my custom font programmatically it is not centered, I guess because the font I can see in IB for the button has another height and width and this is the size considered to center the title. How could I center the title with my custom font?

Thanks!

Comment: show the screenshot. Its probably a problem with your custom font. Not like you stated because of interfere with default font. Check do you have the content mode is centered. I don't know contentMode is available for UIButton or not.

Comment: @DineshRaja content is centered both vertically and horizontally, it seems to be because of the custom font, system provided fonts are perfectly centered... how could I programmatically calculate the frame the labels with my custom font need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the custom font, that it introduced some space below characters. This post solved my problem:

[UIButton custom font vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> > [button setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];