# From iOS6 to iOS7 Issue with edge inset

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uiedgeinsets

I have a problem with title vertical alignment of some  `UIButtons` that is over the central line of the button, this happened because I've used   a custom font that have  a wrong vertical alignment, I fixed this problem in iOS6 with `titleEdgeInsets` and put some pixel of inset on the top value. When I start to update my app to iOS7 I've a inverse problem now the title is under the central line and if I remove the insets the title is on the centre of the button. is there a way for fix this problem both operation system {iOS6, iOS} using the same code?

Comment: You can see also this answer, this was pretty helpful for me to solve a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment/8314197#8314197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked at start the app the  iOS7 or iOS6 and the is set the global variable for the insets
so if is iOS7 this variable have a value else have another. like that I resolve my problem.