# different vertical alignment Font between ios6 and ios7

Tags: ios, ios6, fonts, ios7, vertical-alignment

I have some problem with the vertical alignment Font between iOS6 and iOS7, I have a custom font that in iOS6 was a bit higher then  a centre of vertical alignment in a `UIButton`, so have I done it? I've set the `myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 0, 0)` and I've fixed the issue, but now with the iOS7 have the opposite issue now with iOS7 the font is a bit lower...How i can fix this problem for have the same result in both iOS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find this link on StackOverFlow that similars to what is your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment/8314197#8314197