# Custom Font Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts

In my app, I used custom fonts. It works fine for `UILabel`s, etc...

But the Title is cut from top for Button.

[image]

**"See the S"**

What is happening and how can I resolve this??

Comment: Check this similar question - [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment?rq=1)

Comment: iOS 6 or iOS7? button is created from storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: @Ilario, Thanks for reply! It is created  in Xib

Comment: Try increasing the UILabel's height? :/

Comment: @Anil, It is not Label, It is button.

Comment: button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
minimize font size or increase button height to set characters like g ,s,y,z b etc

Comment: Probably there is another object frame overlapping frame of the button.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `button.contentEdgeInsets` property to align the title within the button, if it is an issue of misligned baseline of the font you can do this

```
button.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment =  UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But not Worked!!

Comment: in my case i had to follow the answer mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment to edit the font file. worth giving a try

Answer (score 0):

a few steps:

1. Include your fonts in your XCode project
2. Make sure that they’re included in the target
3. Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle
4. Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist
5. Find the name of the font
6. Use UIFont and specify the name of the font

detail for this:
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

thanks!

Comment: make the button`size bigger

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the font file that was corrupted.
Try to open the ttf file in your mac, select the 'S' and see if the frame that appears cuts off the letter. 
My solution was to change the ttf file.