# Font rendering issue in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts

I tried to use font BabeNeue which is available at [font-squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bebas-NEUE)

I have used following code

```
<input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" class="checkout">
```

Following CSS

```
input#purchase, input.checkout, .btn-border {
color: #D39229;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 3px #D39229 solid;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
border-radius: 0px;
padding: 4px 20px;
line-height: 18px;
box-sizing: border-box;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
align-items: start;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-family: 'BebasNeue', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

and imported font from my [location](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0730/7477/t/2/assets/fonts.css)

Now font rendered correctly in windows, but it has issue with iPhone and Mac. text is shifting bit up.

[image]

Now if I change button font to Arial, It works fine on all browsers and devices.

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/xngza9n8/2/)

Comment: I believe that is a problem with the font's ascender property, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7535498/2126792

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble's with this font on firefox and chrome (getting the size and line-height right)
I've tinkered with the code a bit and this worked fine for me
(couldn't tell what align-items did though never seen or used it before)

```
input#purchase, input.checkout, .btn-border {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px #D39229 solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #D39229;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* I couldn't tell if you needed this or not so I just left it alone*/
  align-items: start;
}
```

Comment: it is issue with this font, I have fixed by editing the font.

Comment: @Kasma congratulations and best of luck with your project.

Comment: @Kasma, please, could you share how did you fixed it. That is, what did you edit and how did you edit it? Thanks.