# Font Luckiest-Guy not vertically Centered in UILabel

Tags: swift, fonts, uilabel

I am using a font called: Luckiest Guy in a Swift project ([Link to the font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Luckiest+Guy)).
However, in UILabels, it's not vertically aligned to the center even after setting baselineAlignment to the center...
Could you check my code and help me out. Thanks a lot!!

I attached a screen shot here to show the problem (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hxq68dewtzzkxi/IMG_9733.png?dl=0)

```
    var dynamicLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    dynamicLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35) //Frame (the coordinates are changed here to simply the code)

    // *** Color and offset *** //
    dynamicLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    dynamicLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    dynamicLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    dynamicLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0)

    // *** Text alignment *** //
    dynamicLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    dynamicLabel.font = UIFont(name: "LuckiestGuy-Regular", size: 25)
    dynamicLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    dynamicLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    dynamicLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters

    // *** Label corner and border *** //
    dynamicLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    dynamicLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    dynamicLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    dynamicLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0


    // Text
    dynamicLabel.text = "Excellent!"
```

Comment: The working solution is in the comment of accepted answer :D Thanks a lot @Julia Grill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your explanation to what is happening instead is rather vague I assume that the Label isn't really visible, because with the implementation of `dynamicLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center` the text should be aligned

I've tried your code in a sample project and the only two things I noticed that were off were the x and y coordinates of the label (as they're set to zero, so the label doesn't really get displayed anyways) and that you didn't add the label to the view:

```
    let dynamicLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 100))

    // *** Color and offset *** //
    dynamicLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    dynamicLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    dynamicLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    dynamicLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0)

    dynamicLabel.text = "Excellent!"

    // *** Text alignment *** //
    dynamicLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    dynamicLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    dynamicLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    dynamicLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters

    // *** Label corner and border *** //
    dynamicLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    dynamicLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    dynamicLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    dynamicLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    view.addSubview(dynamicLabel)
```

Comment: Hi Julia, thanks for your comments. Sorry for the part that is not clear. In my code, I actually added the label to the view. My problem is that the center of the text is not exactly in the center of my label.. As I'm a newbie, I am not allowed to upload pictures here. But you can check the final effect I got here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hxq68dewtzzkxi/IMG_9733.png?dl=0 Thanks for taking your time

Comment: No worries! What I've found was this blog post that explains how to fix this centring problem for custom fonts: [Post](http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/) // also: there's a Stackoverflow thread that already discussed the same problem of yours: [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8314197/4748900)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Julia! The solution described in the two links you sent fixed my problem perfectly! Cheers! :)