# How to modify font properties if the font is “cut off” at the top or bottom in a UILabel

Tags: android, ios, fonts

How can I increase the height of the font if it gets "cut off" from the top of the UILabel, specifically, when using non English special characters such as `Č`, `Š` or `Ñ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment/8314197#8314197) helped me, however, it is missing a few things.

Download the [Apple Font Tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=font) and install them. Then open the Terminal, navigate to the "Fonts" folder, or open "font Book", find your font, right click to show it in the Finder, copy-paste it somewhere else and then navigate to that folder in Terminal.

Then paste this in the terminal (beware of spaces in the name of the font, put a `\` in front of them):

```
ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d MyFont.ttf
```

This will generate a `MyFont.hhea.xml` file, which you can open with any text editor. Now you can modify the `ascender` & `descender` properties. 
If your font gets cut off at the top, then increase ascender and descender by the same amount.

When you're done editing, paste this in the terminal:

`ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f MyFont.ttf`

This will generate a new `.ttf` file which you can install like a normal font. Works with other font extensions as well, such as `.otf`.